# How can i move from one directory to another using the command ln and a relativ path in linux

Tags: ln

My problem is that I need to move from a directory to another one by only using the `ln` command

So here I have this relative path: `../../10/wsl` and I know I have to create a symlink with `ln` to be able to create a tunnel to the other directory.  Then I will be able to use cd to move.

I tried

- `ln -s filepath`
- `ln -rs filepath`

but nothing works

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If you want to move to another directory, use `cd`. If you want to create a symbolic link, use `ln -s target link_name`, `man ln` for more.

Comment: Are you on Linux? Which one? Your file is "wsl", does this mean you're actually using Windows with WSL?

Answer (score 0):

Does this example help you? I just did this a few hours ago.

Iwantthefiletogohere
Thefiletobemovedishere

```
ln -s /home/orca/Downloads/Thefiletobemovedishere/sixfigureseminarmap.pdf /home/orca/Downloads/Iwantthefiletogohere
```

Answer (score 0):

`man ln` shows:

> ```
> NAME
>       ln - make links between files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME
>        ln [OPTION]... TARGET
>        ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY
>        ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        In the 1st form, create a link to TARGET with the name LINK_NAME.  
>        In the 2nd form, create a link to TARGET in the current directory.
>        In the 3rd and 4th forms,  create  links  to  each TARGET  in 
>        DIRECTORY.  Create hard links by default, symbolic links with 
>        --symbolic.  By de‐fault, each destination (name of new link) 
>        should not already  exist.   When  creating  hard links, each 
>        TARGET must exist.  Symbolic links can hold arbitrary text; if 
>        later resolved, a relative link is interpreted in relation to its 
>        parent directory.
> ```

To make a link using the first form use: `ln -s ../../10/wsl wsl`.
With the second form you should be able to: `ln -s ../../10/wsl`.
Both of these will create `./wsl`.

I see you've already tried the second form, therefore these could be some of the problems you ran into:

```
$ ln ../../10/wsl
ln: ../../10/wsl: hard link not allowed for directory
$ ln -s ../../10/wsl
ln: failed to create symbolic link './wsl': File exists
```

In the first line, we forgot the `-s` flag.  In the second form, we already had a file in the current directory called `./wsl`.  We will need to move or delete it if we want this command to work.  If these aren't your problems, then post your output for further guidance.

Once you have your `ln` command, you can try it out:

```
# The ls command shows the link
$ ls -l
wsl -> ../../10/wsl

# You can cd in and out of that directory:
~ $ cd wsl
~/wsl $ cd ..
~ $

# If you create a file here, you can also see that file appear in the original directory
$ touch wsl/file1
$ ls ../../10/wsl
file1
```